# Saving data to chrome storage via created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, event-listener

I want to create a input and save value button when pressing edit button. Then save the input with created save button in the chrome storage. But nothing happens when I'm trying to press new created button. Nothing dropping in console. I tried alert as well.

HTML

`<div id="area"><button id="edit"><img src="img/edit.png" height="12" width="12" align="center"></button>`

Javascript

```
$("#edit").click(function(e)
    {
        $('#area').append('<input name="theinput" id="theinput" type="text" size="12" placeholder="input">')
        $("#edit" ).remove();
        $('#area').append('<button id="save"><img src="img/save.png" height="12" width="12" align="center"></button>')
});

$('#save').click(function(e)
{
    var value = document.getElementById('theinput').value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'variable': value}, function(){
        console.log("Saved!")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#save` click handler is getting set before the div `#save` exists on the page because the button click on `#edit` is creating the `#save` button. Your `#save` click event is binding to nothing. You want `#save` to be on the page when it loads, but want it to be invisible. You should use css to hide and show it. Something like this.

Add the save button to your HTML

```
<div id="area">
  <button id="edit" class="visible">
    <img src="img/edit.png" height="12" width="12" align="center">
  </button>
  <button id="save" class="hidden"><img src="img/save.png" height="12" width="12" align="center"></button>
</div>
```

And then some javascript to toggle the classes

```
$("#edit").click(function(e){
  $(this).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
  $('#save').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
}
```

And of course the CSS classes

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: @NikitaLvov glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Even I do not understand what you want exactly, when you create your save button, the Jquery code for that button is not binding with any listener. Since you said you do not see anything in the console when you are inside of $('#save').click(), you can use .on() function which is kind of a shorthand for .click(), .change() functions but which is handling your issue in a more straight forward way.

```
    $(document).on('click','#save',function(){
        var value = document.getElementById('theinput').value;
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'variable': value}, function(){
        console.log("Saved!");
      });
    });
```

**Note:** Do not forget to use all of your JQuery code inside $(document).ready() function.